# Xcode compile source file and copy uncompiled source to resources

Tags: xcode, resources, build

I'd like Xcode to compile a .m file in my project into my app, and also copy the uncompiled .m file into my app's Resources. I tried adding the file to both the "Compile Sources" and "Copy Bundle Resources" build phases, but that created a .o file in my app bundle, rather than my original .m.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but you can use shell scripts in your Build Phase.

Just use `cp -p Original/Path\ To/SourceFile.m Some/Where/Else/SourceFile.m`

[image]